# Why is Ficus throwing an exception when I try to add a new field in my case class?

Tags: scala, config

My application parses settings using "typesafe.config" and then converts the `Config` object into an instance of a case class using "ficus". The case class currently has 19 constructor arguments. And everything works normally. However, when I add a new argument and a new corresponding field in my "settings.conf", I get the following exception:

```
An exception or error caused a run to abort: MyCaseClass.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;IZLscala/collection/Seq;Ljava/lang/String;ILscala/concurrent/duration/FiniteDuration;ZLscala/Option;Lscala/Option;ILscala/Option;Lscala/concurrent/duration/FiniteDuration;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)V 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: MyCaseClass.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;IZLscala/collection/Seq;Ljava/lang/String;ILscala/concurrent/duration/FiniteDuration;ZLscala/Option;Lscala/Option;ILscala/Option;Lscala/concurrent/duration/FiniteDuration;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)V
```

I can see the "typesafe.config" is correctly parsing my new field into the `Config` object. But ficus then throws this exception. The new field and the new case class constructor argument have exactly the same name, as they should.

Any ideas why this may be happening?

The concrete problem is documented in the following commits:

1) https://github.com/ceilican/Scorex/commit/133157a6ad070cad7a57624c511ee917133ed5f1

2) https://github.com/ceilican/Scorex/commit/074e0bc5add3c666b0943497a5579f3fd365084d

3) https://github.com/ceilican/Scorex/commit/7c8d3475377a17b2a5383bf3a99d797650ca8bc3

The first two commits are working. With the third one, the exception mentioned above is thrown.

As you can see, there is not much conceptual difference between commits 2 and 3. I don't understand why commit 2 works, whereas commit 3 doesn't.

For a moment I thought it could be because of the large number of arguments in the case class, but the following commit shows that the problem also happens when I add the new field to a smaller case class:

4) https://github.com/ceilican/Scorex/commit/1c253b2b526db1539fa674069232cf02784c4bfb

The same kind of exception is thrown when I try to run the code after commit 4.

Is this a bug in Ficus?

Answer (score 0):

After doing `sbt clean` on the main project and on subprojects, the problem stopped happening. My guess is that Ficus's macro magic generates functions based on my case classes, but they are not re-generated when the case classes are modified. Then, when Ficus tries to use the outdated functions that are incompatible with the new case classes, the exception is thrown.

Interestingly, the lack of re-generation happens only when I modify "nested" case classes. If the config file is:

```
main {
  nested {
    param: 0
  }
}
```

with case classes:

```
case class MainCaseClass(nested: NestedCaseClass)

case class NestedCaseClass(param: Int)
```

Then, modifying `MainCaseClass` does not cause problems, but modifying `NestedCaseClass` does.